# Event Studies: Events common to all firms

Tags: r, events

In event `studies2package`, more specifically `phys2eventtime` function, by the events argument, what if I want to measure the impact of events on all the firms in my data?

How should I proceed with my event study in order to measure the impact of the same event on all firms?

Comment: Hi Julia, show us what you tried so far please. Have you done a little search around?

Comment: Hello J.,I`ve done some research, and mostly what I found mentions event studies specific to one firm, just like the event studies package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eventstudies/vignettes/eventstudies.pdf). I tried searching for references of studies which deal with common events to all firms, but i wasn't successful. Hope someone can help! Maybe you ;)

Comment: Nope, I was reviewing and your question appeared in the "first post" queue. This means I have to help you with the use of the site, even though I know nothing about the technology you're talking about. Your question is clear, just confirm I was right adding the "r" tag, to reach appropriate audience. (+ Be careful if what you need is a specific package for "multi-firm" analysis, because it could be seen here as "spam bait", e.g. someone has the paying package and wants to advertise it.)

Comment: Thank you for adding the R tag!